# How to skip while in do while loop?

Tags: c#

The problem is that I cant write `do while` loop without `while` part ... can I skip it somehow or .. ?

```
 // 9. Keep adding numbers untill you add number 7 twice in a row .
 int a;
 int b;

 do
 {
      Console.WriteLine("add number:");
      a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("add number:");
      b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      if (a == 7 && b == 7)
      {
          break;
          Console.WriteLine("end");

      }
}
```

Comment: How about `while (true) { ... }`

Comment: yep i did it with help from alfie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to have the condition in your while

```
while(a != 7 || b != 7)
{
     Console.WriteLine("add number:");
     a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("add number:");
     b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("end");
```

This will make the loop automatically terminate when it finds that both values are 7

As per @AlexK's answer, you could also make the while have no condition, and just contain `true`

```
while(true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("add number:");
     a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("add number:");
     b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if (a == 7 && b == 7)
     {
         break;
         Console.WriteLine("end");

     }
}
```

This will do the same as the above code, though instead of checking if the values are `7` at the beginning of each loop, it instead will loop infinitely until manually exited inside the loop

You may also notice that the syntax I have used is

```
while(/*condition*/)
{
    //code here
}
```

This is a shorter version of the syntax that you are using, though it acts slightly differently. While the above code sample will never run any code if the condition isn't met when the loop is entered, the below code

```
do
{
    //code here
}
while(/*condition*/);
```

Will always run the code contained inside the `do` at least once, regardless of whether the condition is met or not

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibititles. Either set your condition directly to the `while`-part as Alfie already said or use an infinite loop. This is in particular usefull if you have more than one exit-path for your loop, for instance:

```
while(true)
{
    if(a == 3) break;
    if(b == 7) break;
    // some more code
}
```

Of course this code is quite contrived and could easily be replaced by `if(a == 3 || b == 7) break` but sometimes you can´t (or don´t want to) combine all your conditions into one single. Furthermor this could be usefull if you want to break iteration on some condition but `continue` on another (to reduce nesting of your code for example).